# App open ads show after a permission or share dialogue opens

Tags: android, ios, react-native, admob, react-native-google-mobile-ads

1. There is an issue with the open app ads. when ever there is permission dialogue likelocation, contact for storage dialogueopen by operating system or even an alert like `Alert.alert()` the app open ads appear. this is not the appropriate behaviour for google ads policy.
2. Similarly there is another issue with ad open ads it appear with transparent background. with which native, banner or app contact is visible behind the open app ads.
3. Another issue is that if the interstitial ads appear or inters tail video or rewarded ads the also open app ad appear.
4. similar on share dialogue open and after closing that open app ad appear.

I have done various thing to overcome these issue. some of theme resolve temporary but that is not a good solution.

is there an event with which we can check if the a system dialogue is open or some thing other.

```
useEffect(() => {
      const subscription = AppState.addEventListener('change', nextAppState => {
        if (
          appState.current.match(/inactive|background/) &&
          nextAppState === 'active'
        ) {
          setTimeout(() => {
            if (AdState.canShowAppOpenAd && my_Screen != 'Places') {
              appOpenAd.loaded ? appOpenAd.show() : appOpenAd.load();
            } else {
              if (navigationScreen == 'Places') {
                AdState.canShowAppOpenAd = false;
              } else {
                AdState.canShowAppOpenAd = true;
              }
            }
          }, 1000);
        } else {
          appOpenAd.load();
        }

        appState.current = nextAppState;
        setAppStateVisible(appState.current);
      });
      return () => {
        subscription.remove();
      };
    }, []);
```

Platforms

**Android and iOS**

React Native Info

```
System:
    OS: macOS 13.1
    CPU: (16) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-9880H CPU @ 2.30GHz
    Memory: 7.21 GB / 32.00 GB
    Shell: 5.8.1 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 16.14.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.19 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 8.3.1 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/bin/npm
    Watchman: 2022.12.05.00 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.11.3 - /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 22.2, iOS 16.2, macOS 13.1, tvOS 16.1, watchOS 9.1
    Android SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 2021.2 AI-212.5712.43.2112.8815526
    Xcode: 14.2/14C18 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 11.0.16 - /usr/bin/javac
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 18.1.0 => 18.1.0 
    react-native: 0.70.6 => 0.70.6 
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "NumberLocator",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "postinstall": "patch-package"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.11",
    "@react-native-community/art": "^1.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/clipboard": "^1.5.1",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^9.3.7",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "^4.4.0",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.5.6",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.1",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.7",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.10",
    "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "^4.0.0",
    "geolib": "^3.3.3",
    "google-libphonenumber": "^3.2.31",
    "libphonenumber-js": "^1.10.15",
    "lottie-react-native": "^5.1.4",
    "patch-package": "^6.5.0",
    "postinstall-postinstall": "^2.1.0",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.6",
    "react-native-admob-native-ads": "^0.6.0",
    "react-native-android-location-enabler": "^1.2.2",
    "react-native-android-open-settings": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-app-intro-slider": "^4.0.4",
    "react-native-applovin-max": "^4.1.4",
    "react-native-battery": "^0.1.18",
    "react-native-compass-heading": "^1.4.2",
    "react-native-contacts": "^7.0.5",
    "react-native-cool-speedometer": "1.1.0",
    "react-native-device-info": "^10.3.0",
    "react-native-device-specs": "^0.0.7",
    "react-native-full-battery-status": "^0.1.10",
    "react-native-geolocation-service": "^5.3.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.8.0",
    "react-native-google-mobile-ads": "^8.2.2",
    "react-native-largelist-v3": "^3.1.0-rc.1",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.6.2",
    "react-native-maps": "^1.3.2",
    "react-native-maps-directions": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-navigation-bar-color": "^2.0.2",
    "react-native-neomorph-shadows": "^1.1.2",
    "react-native-pager-view": "^6.1.2",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.1.2",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.6.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.13.0",
    "react-native-responsive-fontsize": "^0.5.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.18.2",
    "react-native-send-intent": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-spring-scrollview": "3.0.2",
    "react-native-svg": "12.5.0",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-system-setting": "^1.7.6",
    "react-native-torch": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-vitals": "^2.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.72.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.1.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```